# remove text in kineticjs

Tags: cordova, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a problem, I have a input where I add text to the canvas image kinetics stage, I can move the text inside the canvas with draggable, but now I want that have a posibility to do double click or something to delete this label text if I want because for example if Im wrong with the text or something similar.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call myText.remove to remove your text from the layer.

myText.remove does not destroy the text object itself--just removes it from the layer.

```
myText.remove();
```

So you could do this to change the text and add it back to the layer

```
myText.setText("Here is my reworded text");
layer.add(myText);
```

If you want to totally destroy your text, just call myText.destroy.

```
myText.destroy();
```

You can listen for doubleclicks on your text like this:

```
myText.on("dblclick",function(){
    this.remove();
    layer.draw();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer....can you show me a little example...Im trying this code in my project...but it's not working...

Comment: The code in my answer is quite complete, but here is a fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9bE9U/

Comment: Hi how to make text dragable after using myText.destroy();

Comment: @Ron Not possible because after myText.destroy() then myText does not exist.  If you want to make an existing Kinetic text object draggable you can do this:  myText.draggable(true);  Cheers!